# How to select possible row in sql

Tags: php, sql, mysql, row

Alright this is my situation:
I have 2 tables: **photos**, **gallery**.
I just want to show all galleries with one photo from each gallery, but I have in **photos**(TABLE) column title_photo.
I want to show that image, which has title_photo='y' of course some images from other gallery doesn't have it(They have title_photo = 'n'). I have this sql

```
SELECT * FROM photos
RIGHT JOIN gallery
ON gallery.code = photos.gallery_code
WHERE photos.title_photo = 'y' 
GROUP BY gallery.id
```

I have 4 galleries and in only one I set in row `(photos TABLE) title_photo = 'y'`. That sql shows only 
one gallery, which has in `photos(TABLE) set title_photo = 'y'`.

My question is:

Is there any solution to show other galleries(they have `photos.title_photo = 'n'`) and show gallery which has `title_photo = 'y'`?

Comment: Try `WHERE photos.title_photo IN('y','n') GROUP BY gallery.id,photos.title_photo`

Comment: It doesn't work, it shows only rows with 'n'.

Comment: OK, now it shows that column with 'y' but it show 2 rows from **photos** table with same gallery_code

Comment: What's the purpose of `GROUP BY` here? You're using a pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Please read this and revise your query accordingly. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Go to sqlfiddle.com and load up sample data. Your code quite a few potential trouble areas: the `GROUP BY gallery.id` combined with `SELECT *`, the `GROUP BY` with no aggregate functions and the `RIGHT JOIN` combined with `WHERE photos.title_photo = 'y'` are three I can immediately see

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want the "first" photo in each gallery, where "first" is defined by the value 'y' in title_photo if that is present. If a gallery has no title photo, we'll use the photo with the smallest photo.id in that gallery as the "first".

For starters, we need to find the pseudo-id for the "first" photo in each gallery. Let's try this:

```
   SELECT photos.gallery_code,
          MIN(photos.id + (100000000 * photos.title_photo <> 'y')) AS pseudoid
     FROM photos
 GROUP BY photos.gallery_code
```

This gives us either a single genuine photos.id, or one that's one hundred million too large, for each gallery.  Next we need to turn that back into a usable photo id, like so.

```
   SELECT gallery_code, (pseudoid MOD 100000000) AS id
     FROM (
        SELECT photos.gallery_code,
               MIN(photos.id + (100000000 * photos.title_photo <> 'y')) AS pseudoid
          FROM photos
      GROUP BY photos.gallery_code 
     ) AS firsts
```

Next, we need to join that list of first photos to the photos and gallery table.

```
 SELECT p.whatever, g.whatever
   FROM (
       SELECT gallery_code, (pseudoid MOD 100000000) AS id
         FROM (
            SELECT photos.gallery_code,
                   MIN(photos.id + (100000000 * photos.title_photo <> 'y')) AS pseudoid
              FROM photos
          GROUP BY photos.gallery_code 
         ) AS firsts
        ) AS f
   JOIN gallery AS g ON f.gallery_code = g.code
   JOIN photos AS p  ON f.id = p.id
  ORDER BY (whatever you need here)
```

See what we're doing here?  We're using a query to generate the gallery/first-photo relationship using the specified logic.

Then we're employing that as a subquery (virtual table). We're joining it to the two data tables to retrieve the information we need, just for those first photos.

Pro-tip: Don't use SELECT * in application software. Be specific about the columns you need in your result sets.

Pro-tip: Don't use the nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` unless you're really expert. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: still same, it shows another photo with title_photo = 'n' and not 'y'

Comment: Perhaps you can troubleshoot by examining the results of my first subquery. I obviously don't have your data, so I can't troubleshoot.